# How does the after method works in tkinter?

Tags: python, animation, tkinter, conways-game-of-life

I am new at programing and I am trying to make a simple animation to better learn. I have just learned python (still nooby) and starting to learn tkinter.
I am trying to make an animation of the Conway's Game of Life because it has very simple principles and looks cool.
I have manage to actually make my code work but I really dont understand how.
The thing is that the method after I cannot understand how it works.

The part of the code that I dont understand is the method called start.
I really dont understand how "loop finished" can be printed before startloop function returns None (which it should be the same as saying the animation hasnt stop yet)

```py
import tkinter as tk


width = 1400
height = 600
dist = 5
drawlines = False

celstate = set()
numcol = width//dist
numrow = height//dist

def getdeadcells(setcells):
    global celstate
    deadcells = set()
    for cell in setcells:
        i, j = cell
        list = [(i-1, j-1), (i, j-1), (i+1, j-1),
                (i-1, j), (i+1, j), (i-1, j+1), (i, j+1), (i+1, j+1)]
        for cel in list:
            if cel not in celstate:
                deadcells.add(cel)
    return deadcells

def getnewstate():
    def neight(cell):
        i, j = cell
        count = 0
        list = [(i-1, j-1), (i, j-1), (i+1, j-1),
                (i-1, j), (i+1, j), (i-1, j+1), (i, j+1), (i+1, j+1)]
        for cel in list:
            if cel in celstate:
                count +=1
        return count

    global celstate, numcol, numrow
    alivecells = celstate.copy()
    deadcells = getdeadcells(alivecells)
    newstate = set()
    for cell in alivecells:
        neigh = neight(cell)
        if neigh == 2 or neigh == 3:
            newstate.add(cell)
    for cell in deadcells:
        neigh = neight(cell)
        if neigh == 3:
            newstate.add(cell)
    if newstate == celstate:
        return None
    else:
        celstate = newstate
        if len(newstate) == 0:
            return ""
        else:
            return newstate

def getcords(x, y):
    col = x//dist
    row = y//dist
    return (col, row)


class GUI():
    def __init__(self, master, width, height, dist):
        master.geometry("{}x{}".format(width, height))
        master.bind("<Key>", self.start)
        self.master = master
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.dist = dist
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=width, height=height)
        self.canvas.pack(expand=True)
        self.drawlimits(dist)

    def start(self, event):
        if event.keycode == 32 or event.keycode == 13:
            def startloop():
                newstate = getnewstate()
                if newstate == None:
                    return None
                elif newstate == "":
                    self.canvas.delete("rect")
                    return None
                else:
                    self.canvas.delete("rect")
                    self.fillrects(list(newstate))
                    self.master.after(100, startloop)
            startloop()
            print("loop finished")

    def drawlimits(self, dist):
        if self.width % dist == 0 and self.height % dist == 0:
            self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.drawcells)
            self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.drawcells)
            self.canvas.bind("<B3-Motion>", self.killcell)
            self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-3>", self.killcell)
            if drawlines:
                xsteps = self.width/dist
                ysteps = self.height/dist
                for num in range(int(xsteps-1)):
                    self.canvas.create_line((num+1)*dist, 0, (num+1)*dist, self.height)
                for num in range(int(ysteps-1)):
                    self.canvas.create_line(0, (num+1)*dist, self.width, (num+1)*dist)

    def drawcells(self, event):
        cell = getcords(event.x, event.y)
        if cell not in celstate:
            self.fillrects([cell])
            celstate.add(cell)

    def killcell(self, event):
        cell = getcords(event.x, event.y)
        if cell in celstate:
            celstate.remove(cell)
            col, row = cell
            tag = "{},{}".format(col, row)
            obj.canvas.delete(tag)

    def fillrects(self, cords):
        for gcords in cords:
            col, row = gcords
            tag = "{},{}".format(col,row)
            dist = self.dist
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(col*dist, row*dist, (col+1)*dist, (row+1)*dist,
            fill="black", tags=(tag, "rect"))


root = tk.Tk()
obj = GUI(root, width, height, dist)
root.mainloop()
```

The code works as following:
I only save the cells that are alive in the celstate set.
I then find the deadcells that could become alive and iterate over the dead and alive cells in the

If the celstate is the same as the previous or theres no alive cells: then the function getnewstate returns None.

In the start method I then call the function getnewstate and draw its content until celstate returns None (with the function startloop that calls itself with the after method).
I dont understand why "loop finished" can be printed if startloop hasnt stop yet.
Even though I dont understand this part the code still works as intended which just makes it more anoyingly mistirious for me.
Can anyone help clarify whats going on??

- The dist variable represents the cell size in pixels
- You can draw new cells using the left button of the mouse or erase existing ones using the right button. (The cool part is that you can do that while the animation is still going)

I'm sure the problem comes because I dont really understand how the mainloop works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tkinter `after` method effectively sends a message to the mainloop() to run the callback function in n milliseconds.  Your `start` function sends this message then prints "loop finished". It doesn't wait for the after callback to return before carrying on execution.  100 ms later it calls startloop() and recalculates and displays the new grid. If it did wait for the callback to return it would freeze the UI while it waited.  The after function lets you run code after a delay but still have an active ui.

I've amended your start function to print "loop finished" instead of returning None on your exit parts of the code.

```
def start(self, event):
    if event.keycode == 32 or event.keycode == 13:
        def startloop():
            newstate = getnewstate()
            if newstate == None:                
                print("loop finished")
            elif newstate == "":
            self.canvas.delete("rect")
                print("loop finished")
            else:
                self.canvas.delete("rect")
                self.fillrects(list(newstate))
                self.master.after(100, startloop)
        startloop()
```

One problem you may have is that the game of life can reach stable conditions that return to the same sate every two cyles.  Some shapes have even longer cycle periods.

HTH